# Reading both English and Korean strings from a JSON file using Python?

Tags: python, json, python-unicode

I'm trying to read a JSON file containing information about songs in a playlist using Python, but seem to be having an issue with reading Korean and Chinese characters?

My code is as follows:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('.../playlist.json', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for playlist in data['playlists']:
    for item in playlist['items']:
        pprint(item['track']['trackName'])
```

When I run it, all track names that are wholly in English print fine, but for those containing either Korean or Chinese characters, I get an error saying:

```
  File "...\parse.py", line 10, in <module>
    pprint(item['track']['trackName'])
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pprint.py", line 53, in pprint
    printer.pprint(object)
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pprint.py", line 148, in pprint
    self._format(object, self._stream, 0, 0, {}, 0)
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\pprint.py", line 185, in _format
    stream.write(rep)
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 5-6: character maps to <undefined>
```

EDIT: It also seems to fall over when it hits the `′` character, giving the UnicodeEncodeError: `'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2032'`

Comment: It's not having trouble reading - it's having trouble _writing_. Windows prompts cannot write utf-8 by default, so you'll need to change the codepoint with `chcp 65001` and/or change the system encoding to utf-8. Observe this with the minimal program `print("你好，世界")`

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Sorry, I'm just starting out with all this. I'm using VS Code

Comment: You should just type **chcp 65001** in terminal like @erip mentioned.If you are running a script via vscode for an example you should just type the command.. or if you wanna do that with python just import os and use `os.system("chcp 65001")`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I ended up changing my system locale to use the beta option with UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Do you redirect the output?

Python uses UTF-8 for console output so all characters can be printed. But when stdout is redirected (e.g. pipe or file), Python uses ANSI code page.

You can set `PYTHONUTF8=1` environment variable to use UTF-8 for the defaut text encoding. See https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#utf-8-mode